# Resources for learning tree-based genetic programming in LISP?

Tags: tree, lisp, genetic-algorithm, genetic-programming

I want to try to evolve a program in LISP that can play Go. What are some good websites/tutorials/textbooks/PDFs that will teach me about tree-based genetic programming in LISP?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the book [Essentials of Metaheuristics](https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/book/metaheuristics/), chapter 4.3. The book is free to download and is a really great resource for metaheuristics and evolutionary computation. But it's not a tutorial on programming a genetic programming system.